# Using sha256 to hash a variable in Python

Tags: python, sha256

I am having trouble using sha256 hash for a variable. Here is my code:

```
var = 'password'
hashedWord = sha256(b var).hexdigest()
print(hashedWord)
```

I know it would be easier to do this:

```
hashedWord = sha256(b'password').hexdigest()
print(hashedWord)
```

But I don't want to do it that way. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *encode* strings to bytes:

```
var = 'password'
hashedWord = sha256(var.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
```

Pick an encoding that works for your text; UTF-8 can encode all of Unicode but that may not produce the hash signature you are looking for; this depends on what *other* systems think the signature is.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [Martijn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) solution would be to store a byte string in the `var` variable.

`var = b'password'
hashedWord = sha256(var).hexdigest()
print(hashedWord)`